# Wordpress post not displaying

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

header.php - file

I'am new to Wordpress scripting, can't figure out what i've done wrong? My post are not displaying

```
<nav class="subnav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu')); ?>
</nav>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <article>
                <div id="overview" class="tab">
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile;?>   

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where did you put that code?

Comment: Set latest post for home page from settings, if you use the code in home page.

Comment: @Karthik to header.php file

Comment: Which theme are you using? Are you developing one?

Comment: @Karthik making my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header>

        <nav class="subnav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu')); ?>
        </nav>

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article>
                        <div id="overview" class="tab">
                            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                <?php endwhile;?>   

            <?php endif; ?>

    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

> Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In header.php you should add something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<nav class="subnav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu')); ?>
</nav>
```

In your front-page.php or home.php or index.php** include header.php with a wordpress specific function `get_header()` then render your menu, posts etc like this:

```
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <article>
        <div id="overview" class="tab">
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please refer [this](https://github.com/mattbanks/WordPress-Starter-Theme)

** If you are confused which php file to use please study WordPress [hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code on page.php or post.php otherwise you can create template and put below code and assign page to this template.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <article>
                <div id="overview" class="tab">
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile;?> 
    <?php endif; ?>
```